# Why are name_tag and nametag different ID items?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I enter `/give @s name` into my chat on MCBE, the autocomplete shows both `name_tag` and `nametag` as viable options for items.
[image: nametag and name_tag]
Why do they have separate IDs? They seem to stack.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 but the weird thing is it was introduced in the 1.16.100 update and it has never been a part of the game and it is weird that only this item is affected (maybe because of the legacy id?). Maybe it is, but the weird thing is **they stack**. I was wondering if there was some technical difference for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unresolved bug: ID changes left behind legacy IDs](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-100267)

> The ID changes from this beta are a great step to parity, but now duplicate items exist.
>
> All items that changed their ID have their old ID still as a valid value, eg `record_mellohi` alongside `music_disc_mellohi`.
> This affects both renamed items and items which got split up (dyes, boats, spawn eggs).
>
> Affected items:
>
> - Scute
> - Enchanted Apple
> - Dark Oak Sign
> - Boat
> - Lodestone Compass
> - Raw Cod
> - Tropical Fish
> - Cooked Cod
> - Dye
> - Melon
> - Glistering Melon
> - Spawn Egg
> - Fire Charge
> - Empty Map
> - Carrot on a Stick
> - Nether Star
> - Firework Rocket
> - Firework Star
> - Iron Horse Armor
> - Gold Horse Armor
> - Diamond Horse Armor
> - Leather Horse Armor
> - Raw Mutton
> - Cooked Mutton
> - Popped Chorus Fruit
> - Totem of Undying
> - Music Disc - 13
> - Music Disc - Cat
> - Music Disc - Blocks
> - Music Disc - Chrip
> - Music Disc - Far
> - Music Disc - Mall
> - Music Disc - Mellohi
> - Music Disc - Stal
> - Music Disc - Strad
> - Music Disc - Ward
> - Music Disc - 11
> - Music Disc - Wait
> - Music Disc - Pigstep
> - Banner Pattern
> - Name Tag